# Understanding proof of isomorphism in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

I’m reading a book on Category Theory and the following theorem was enunciated:

A function $f:X\to Y$ is an isomorphism iff for every object $Z$ the pushforward $f_*: C(Z,X)\to C(Z,Y)$ is an isomorphism of sets.

He then goes on to prove it, but I didn’t quite understood everything. My biggest confusion is encapsulated with the following example. Consider the following Category:

[image]

In the example, $f$ is an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$, yet, the pushforward $f_*$ does not seem to be an isomorphism between $C(Z,X)$ and $C(Z,Y)$, since $C(Z,X)=\{h\}$ while $C(Z,Y)=\{h \circ f, h\circ g\}$.

Can someone explain to me what’s wrong with my example?

Comment: What is $f^{-1}\circ g$?

Comment: Thanks, @EricWofsey. I see your point. It’s indeed an isomorphism, I forgot to consider $f^{-1} g h$ in the set $C(Z,X)$. :)

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Topology A Categorical Approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_\ast$ is injective because if $f_\ast(g)=f_\ast(g')$ for $g,g' \in C(Z,X )$ then $g' \circ f  = g \circ f$ and right cancellation with $f$ (compose both sides with $f^{-1}$ etc) gives $g=g'$ and $f_\ast$ is onto as when $h \in C(Z,Y)$ then $f_\ast(h \circ f^{-1})=h$ by definitions. So one direction seems pretty clear. (isomorphism implies set isomorphism aka bijection). Or is that not the direction you're worried about? Why try to construct the (faulty, as Eric pointed out) example ? Where's your doubt in the proof of the fact itself?

Comment: It’s alright. I was just trying to get a “tacit” feeling for the proof. And when I drew the diagram, I didn’t understand how the theorem followed.